# Хочу сделать функцию или метод, который возращает максимум из массива JS

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Есть база данных она в себе хранит числа в одном из столбцов. Я хочу взять этот столбец, найти там максимум и к этому максимуму прибавить один (допустим один) и эту число вернуть (прибавленное на один).

```
$psql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mine_info ();
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS id_k1 integer PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS N_mine varchar(20) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS name_mine text NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS adress varchar(70) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS full_name_of_direcor text NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mine_info ADD IF NOT EXISTS phone_number varchar(30) NOT NULL;";
$res = $conn->query("select * from mine_info")
```

Эта меня интересует эта таблица она находиться в базе данных я хочу взять столбец id_k1

```
function id_k1+1(){
include 'ссылка на файл/.php';
while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo($row["id_k1"]);}
}
```

А как что дальше хз или я может вообще не то делаю кто-то может подсказать

Comment: Почему бы не реализовать данную задачу через запрос `select max` например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заголовок и содержание вопроса сильно отличаются.

Возможно нужно что-то такое

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','db_name');
    
echo getMaxIdK1($conn);

function getMaxIdK1($conn) {
    $res = $conn->query('SELECT MAX(id_k1) AS id FROM mine_info');
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $row['id']++; // id + 1
    return $row['id'];
}
```